# Rest calls with multiple lookup fields for reverse lookup

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

In the Django rest framework, is there a way to have multiple lookup fields? I know it doesn't sound very **REST** friendly.

I have a `Company` model, and I want to list them through their country first, and then by a slug field, something like: `/companies/<iso_country>/<slug>/`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 14):

Create mixin like:

```
class MultipleFieldLookupMixin(object):
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
```

and add this mixin to your viewset:

```
class YourCountryViewSet(MultipleFieldLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_fields = ('iso_country', 'slug')

...
```

source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try whenever possible. It sounds like what I needed for the job.

Comment: in such case, what is the url patterns, should we register a new pattern? Or what is the url for `model-detail` request? like `example.com/api/pk/` was for single lookup field, now is it `example.com/api/iso_country/slug/` ?

Comment: yeah, url: `example.com/api/<iso_country>/<slug>/`

Comment: You may want to update your answer with this:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/commit/b11f37eaf314b983c7a21abcea231f69ea31da1b

Basically, the example in the documentation was missing the object level permission check.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a router, I think you can do something like:

```
router.register(r'companies/(?P<iso_country>[^/.]+)/', YourCompanyViewSet, 'company-base')
```

Where you have to define `slug` as your `lookup_field` in your ViewSet.

Then for example, your class will look something like

```
class YourCountryViewSet(GenericViewSet):
     lookup_field = 'slug'

    def create(self, request, iso_country):
        ...

    def retrieve(self, request, iso_country, slug):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested several answers for this topic, and decided compiling those answer into this approach:

(This is an example using `Permission` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`)

```
"""
Example serializers
"""

from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from rest_framework import serializers


class ContentTypeReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    ContentType read serializer
    """
    app_label = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, max_length=100)
    model = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = ContentType
        fields = '__all__'


class PermissionReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Permission read serializer
    """
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, max_length=255)
    content_type = ContentTypeReadSerializer(read_only=True)
    codename = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields = '__all__'


"""
Viewsets mixins
"""

from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404


class MultipleLookupFieldsMixin(object):
    """
    Multiple lookup fields mixin
    """
    lookup_fields = None

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        filters = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if field in self.kwargs:
                if self.kwargs[field] != '':
                    filters[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        if len(filters) == 0:
            return queryset
        return queryset.filter(**filters)
      

"""
Example views
"""

from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from rest_framework import viewsets
from common.viewsets import MultipleLookupFieldsMixin
from . import serializers


class PermissionViewSet(MultipleLookupFieldsMixin,
                        viewsets.mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        viewsets.mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                        viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    Permission viewset
    """
    queryset = Permission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PermissionReadSerializer
    lookup_fields = ['content_type__app_label', 'codename']
    lookup_field = 'codename'


"""
Example urls
"""

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from . import views


router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'permission/?(?P<content_type__app_label>\w+|)', views.PermissionViewSet, basename='permission')


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

With this approach, you can have 3 working endpoints:

```
/permission/
/permission/{content_type__app_name}/
/permission/{content_type__app_name}/{codename}/
```

Nevertheless, this is just a hacky alternative to dedicated nested routing libraries like [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)