# Customize viewset to get an item id combine of slug and uuid Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, uuid

I want to get each single item from my database by a id combine of slug and uuid. In my model I have:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='published')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('name-of-the-view', kwargs={'uuid': self.id, 'slug': self.slug})
```

In my view I am using ModelViewSet:

```
class ProductList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_object(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):
        item = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return generics.get_object_or_404(Product, id=item)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

In my urls I am using router:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import ProductList

app_name = 'products'

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', ProductList, basename='product')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

How can I customize it so I can get not just the `self.kwargs.get('pk')` but also the slug from the link.

I mean that I want to have links to each iteam like this: "item-name-25b6e133" and "item-name-11ac4431", where the first part is the slug and the second is the uuid. The slug should be automatically created of `name` field by the POST request.

Using path it would look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>-<uuid:uuid>/', some_view, name='name-of-the-view'),
]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365906/rest-calls-with-multiple-lookup-fields-for-reverse-lookup) might help